# Case insensitive input and any advice for improvement

Tags: java, string, if-statement, case-insensitive

I am working on a rock paper scissors game project and I would like to know how to allow the user to input multiple types of the same word. If the user typed "ROCK", "rock", or "RoCk" I want the program to allow it to proceed as valid input. Also, this is my first project by myself and if you have any advice or criticism please let me know. I want to get better at programming and will gladly take any advice. Thank you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Displays what the game is
    System.out.println("Rock! Paper! Scissors!");

    String[] random = {"Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"};

    //Making the computer choice random
    String randomString = random[(int) (Math.random() * random.length)];

    //Telling the user to chose between rock paper and scissors
    System.out.println("Rock Paper or Scissors?");

    //User input
    String User;

    //If User doesn't enter Rock, Paper, or Scissors they will get an error message and have to try again
    do {
        User = input.nextLine();
        if (!User.equals("Rock") && !User.equals("Paper") && !User.equals("Scissors")) {
            System.out.println("ERROR Please enter \"Rock\" \"Paper\" or \"Scissors\" ");
        }
    } while (!User.equals("Rock") && !User.equals("Paper") && !User.equals("Scissors"));

    //Displays what the user chose
    if (User.equals("Rock")) {
        System.out.println("User has chosen: Rock!");
    }
    if (User.equals("Paper")) {
        System.out.println("User has chosen: Paper!");
    }
    if (User.equals("Scissors")) {
        System.out.println("User has chosen: Scissors!");
    }

    //Telling the user what the computer has chosen
    System.out.println("Computer has chosen: " + randomString + "!");

    //If the user's choice equals the computers choice the game is a tie
    if (User.equals("Rock") && randomString.equals("Rock")) {
        System.out.println("It is a tie!");
    }
    if (User.equals("Paper") && randomString.equals("Paper")) {
        System.out.println("It is a tie!");
    }
    if (User.equals("Scissors") && randomString.equals("Scissors")) {
        System.out.println("It is a tie!");
    }

    //Deciding who wins if both User and computer chose something different
    if (User.equals("Rock") && randomString.equals("Paper")) {
        System.out.println("Computer has won!");
    }
    if (User.equals("Rock") && randomString.equals("Scissors")) {
        System.out.println("User has won!");
    }
    if (User.equals("Paper") && randomString.equals("Scissors")) {
        System.out.println("Computer has won!");
    }
    if (User.equals("Paper") && randomString.equals("Rock")) {
        System.out.println("User has won!");
    }
    if (User.equals("Scissors") && randomString.equals("Paper")) {
        System.out.println("User has won!");
    }
    if (User.equals("Scissors") && randomString.equals("Rock")) {
        System.out.println("Computer has won!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `toLowerCase()`. Treat every input in lowercase format.

Comment: All of the conditions like `if (User.equals("Rock")) {` are unnecessary: you've already checked it is one of those things. Just concatenate the user's choice to the string.

Comment: About the criticism of the project, please ask to the [codereview.se]. This would be a better place for a working solution seeking advice on improvement.

Answer (score 5):

`String.equalsIgnoreCase(String str)` meets your needs. It will compare two strings ignoring case.

**Example:** In your case, you can use `User.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
    User = input.nextLine();
    if (!User.equals("Rock") && !User.equals("Paper") && !User.equals("Scissors")) {
        System.out.println("ERROR Please enter \"Rock\" \"Paper\" or \"Scissors\" ");
    }
} while (!User.equals("Rock") && !User.equals("Paper") && !User.equals("Scissors"));
```

You keep repeating yourself here.

You've already got an array with all the options:

```
String[] random = {"Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"};
```

So just use this:

```
while (true) {
    User = input.nextLine();
    Optional<String> r = Stream.of(random).findFirst(User::equalsIgnoreCase);
    if (r.isPresent()) {
      User = choice; // get in the expected case
      break;
    }
    System.out.println("ERROR Please enter \"" + String.join("\", \"", random) + "\"");
}
```